Zoho CRM integration with Catalyst
Does Zoho CRM support any integration with Catalyst Serverless/AppSail. How to fetch data from CRM and move it to third party applications ?
I want to integrate my Catalyst application with Zoho CRM. Can you share any help documentation to integrate with Zoho_CRM?
Is there any native integration to integrate Zoho Catalyst with Zoho_CRM?

As of now, Catalyst does not have any native integration to integrate with Zoho CRM. You can integrate your application with Zoho CRM using the Zoho CRM rest api's via Catalyst. You can invoke the API from the Catalyst functions in order to integrate with Zoho CRM.
You can try their lead manager tutorial where they have performed CRUD operations on the Zoho CRM Lead Module from your catalyst application using Zoho CRM API.
Kindly check on this tutorial : https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/tutorials/leadmanager/nodejs/introduction/

You can integrate Zoho CRM using the Zoho CRM Rest API. You can invoke the Zoho CRM API from the Catalyst functions in order to integrate with Zoho CRM.
We would suggest you try this lead manager tutorial where we perform CRUD operations on the Zoho CRM Lead Module from your catalyst application using Zoho CRM API.
